# Stripe Rules object for Classes not working? How to fix it?

Tags: stripe-payments, strip, laravel-cashier

const stripe = Stripe('{{env('STRIPE_KEY')}}');
const elements = stripe.elements();

const style = {
base: {
color: '#32325d',
fontSize: '16px',
'::placeholder': {
color: '#aab7c4'
},
':-webkit-autofill': {
color: '#32325d',
},
},
invalid: {
color: '#fa755a',
iconColor: '#fa755a',
':-webkit-autofill': {
color: '#fa755a',
},
},
rules: {
'.Input': {
border: '1px solid red',
boxShadow: '0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03), 0px 3px 6px rgba(18, 42, 66, 0.02)',
},
},
};

const options = {
style: style,
disabled: false,
hideIcon: false,
iconStyle: "default",
}

const auBankAccount = elements.create('auBankAccount', options);

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`rules` is specifically for the [Elements Appearance API](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/appearance-api). According to Stripe's docs, this API can't be used with individual Elements (like auBankAccount) so `rules` should be removed from your `style` object.

If you really want to use `rules`, you'll need to switch to using the PaymentElement instead.